# Integral of an expression including a fraction having modified Bessel functions of the first kind on both numerator and denominator

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I am looking for an analytic result of the following integral
$$\iint_0^\infty  {{\rm{d}}x{\rm{d}}y{x^2}{y^2}\exp \left\{ { - {\alpha _1}{x^2} - {\alpha _2}{y^2}} \right\}\frac{{{\rm{I}}_1^2\left[ {\beta xy} \right]}}{{{{\rm{I}}_0}\left[ {\beta xy} \right]}}}$$
where ${\rm{I}}_0(\cdot), {\rm{I}}_1(\cdot)$ are the zero- and first-order modified Bessel functions of the first kind, respectively, and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta$ are positive constants.

I have referred to a book named "*Tables of some indefinite integrals of Bessel functions of integer order*" but did not find a solution.

It will be super appreciated if there are some ideas.

Comment: Changing variables to $z = \beta x y$ allows you to integrate out $x$ with result $$\frac{z^2 I_1(z){}^2 K_0(t z)}{\beta ^3 I_0(z)}$$ with $t = 2 \sqrt{\alpha _1 \alpha _2}/\beta$ but that isn't a standard integral or otherwise helpful either.

Comment: @student  A revealing idea, thanks!